# ASP HyperLinkField setting simple value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a datasource Url that databinds perfectly. When I try to put the (working) url to GridView.HyperLinkField -> NavigateUrl it does not work..... How can I get the NavigateUrl property to point at just my link and nothing else ?

BR/Christer

Comment: Need to be more specific here, as this functionality works as it is, so there might be something you are doing wrong. Post details about how you databind this column, and how exactly this does not work (error, wrong link, no link at all, etc)

Comment: <asp:GridView runat="Server" id="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
       <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Documents" NavigateUrl="Url" DataTextField="Url" Text="Title"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Comment: Sorry I forgot the code itself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
( (HyperLink) GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).NavigateUrl
```

you must calculat where is hyperlink index 0 1 2 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using "DataNavigateUrlFields" instead of "NavigateUrl" .